# Ionic, Angular : 3-position switch

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, mobile, ionic-framework

I would like to ask that someone know about UI component like on image below? I yes, post link please.

Many thanks for any advice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [Range](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#range)?

[Check example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMbOJd)

```
<input type="range" name="volume" ng-model="data.volume" min="0" max="2" value="1">
```

Comment: Thanks, but range input is natively displayed horizontal. How to display it vertical?